# $\epsilon-n$ proof reverse

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I know that $\lim \frac{1}{n} = 0$ as n approaches infinity. I proved it using epsilon-N. But if I am to say, I want to prove that this does NOT converge to one, how would I go on about this? Since I want to prove that it does not converge to one, then $|1/n-1| \geq \epsilon$. Now

$$\left|\frac1n -1\right| = \left|\frac{1-n}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon= |1-n|\geq \epsilon |n|$$

this is where I am stuck. How would I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good review of logic and negations.

**Proof that $x_n \to L$:** For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$.

**Proof that $x_n \not\to L$:** There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$, there exists $n\geq N$ such that $|x_n-L|\geq\epsilon$.

In your case, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $L=1$. What $\epsilon$ works here?

Comment: $\epsilon = 1/2?$

Answer (score 1):

The definition of convergence requires a fact to be true for every positive $\epsilon.$ So in order to disprove convergence you merely need to find **one** value of $\epsilon$ for which the fact is false.

Setting $\epsilon =2$ won’t work, because once $1/n$ is less than $1$ unit from $0$ it is less than $2$ units from $1.$
But perhaps you can see some $\epsilon$ that might work.

Comment: how do you usually see what $\epsilon$ is required to be? I was guessing $\epsilon = 1/2$ but idk how you check wether this is correct or incorrect

Comment: For $\epsilon =1/2$ you need to show that no matter how large $N$ is, there is always $n>N$ such that $|1/n-1|\geq 1/2.$ I think what you have already done is a good start.

Comment: So $N$ is arbitary, that means $n=3$ should hold?

Comment: Technically if you only had the inequality for $n=3$ you would not have shown that $N=1000$ (for example) does not satisfy the convergence condition. But you are lucky here because you can try showing the inequality for every $n\geq 3.$ That is more than you need for non-convergence, but that's OK.

Comment: wouldnt $\epsilon=1/3$  also work, given that i find a $n>N$ or any arbitary $\epsilon>0$ also?

Comment: or if $N$ arbitary and $n=N+2$

Comment: $\epsilon=1/3$ should be fine too.